# Порядок выполнения тасков?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Здравствуйте, имеется вот такой код:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Method(a));
Method(b);
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как так получается, что иногда Method(b) начинает выполняться раньше, чем Method(a)?  Method() начинается с lock()

И в случае:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Method(a));
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Method(b));
```

Есть гарантия что они запустятся последовательно? Т.е. сначала точно начнет выполняться Method(a), а следом Method(b)? И если нет, то как правильно сделать?

Comment: Разрешите поинтересоваться, а зачем вам это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет никакой гарантии. Запуститься может даже 5-ый таск первым.
Если хотите точный запуск по очереди - вызывайте новый поток "матрешкой" при старте предыдущего.

UPD:
@PavelMayorov предлагает использовать await и TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: К сожалению я привел упрощенный пример, на самом деле оба таска могут создаваться в разных потока.Я так понял что сделать так чтобы 2 потока запускались в порядке их создания никак нельзя?

Comment: @AntonPopov так ведь в вашем случае порядок создания потоков точно так же неопределен...

Comment: Гарантированно - нельзя.
Но если речь идет только о 2-х потоках, вы можете во втором потоке в цикле проверять (например через атомарную переменную) - запущен ли 1-й поток и если нет, ставить на паузу 2-й на долю секунды.

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk вот только не так!

Comment: @PavelMayorov Предложите свой вариант, мне самому любопытно

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk самый простой вариант - не запускать задачу раньше времени. Дальше идут await и TaskCompletionSource.

Comment: Как я понял из условий, не запускать раньше времени - не вариант. Про await знаю, про TaskCompletionSource не знал, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Task ставится планировщиком в очередь на выполнение и обещает когда-нибудь выполниться, но запуск прямо сейчас не гарантируется, например нету не одного свободного потока в пуле => запуск может быть совершенно в произвольном порядке.